# Facing Issue with Unit testing in Grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-2.0, spock

I need to get messagesource to get access `message.properties` file in simple groovy class(Exception class) so that i am using `Holders.getGrailsApplication()`. My problem is `Holders.getGrailsApplication()` is getting null when i execute unit test case.It works fine if i deploy it in web server.
Variable :-

```
static def grailsApplicationCntx=Holders.getGrailsApplication().getMainContext().getBean(‘messageSource’)
```

Error:-

```
`Failure: testActivateService_Case1(com.xyz.ActivationServiceTests)
| java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
at com.xyz.DatabaseService.addBankUser(DatabaseService.groovy:11)
at com.xyz.RegisterService.register(RegisterService.groovy:39)
at com.xyz.ActivationServiceTests.setUp(ActivationServiceTests.groovy:60)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getMainContext() on null object
at com.xyz.exception.Exception.(Exception.groovy:55)
… 4 more
```

Comment: Have you tried to run this test with `GrailsUnitTestMixin`? (http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/test/mixin/support/GrailsUnitTestMixin.html)

Comment: Yes i am using the annotation but i think application context is not getting load in respective class when unit test get executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to inject messageSource. It is already available there.Just use

```
messageSource.addMessage("foo.bar", request.locale, "My Message")
```

Comment: messageSource is not accessible in simple groovy class.